# VMWARE Unable to open terminal from desktop

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I just installed VMWARE and RHEL 5.4 on it on my Windows desktop. I am not sure how to start - shutdown it either but I am doing the same by clicking on close button associated with the VMWARE window. It states a confirmation message to suspend the VM to which I say "Yes".

Next time when I start VMWARE by clicking on the VM icon and selecting "Play Virtual Machine" it opens VM window. Now I try to open a terminal window from desktop shortcut menu option - the mouse cursor shows that something is getting loaded but after that everything remains as it was. The terminal never opens up. The mouse pointer returns to normal arrow.

I am missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You just suspended a VM. If you want to shutdown it - go to the VM menu and select "shutdown VM". There another menu item - "Power Off" if you select it and your RHEL VM have VMware Tools installed that the VM has a signal to power off gracefully (instead of simply switching off, which like to remove power coord).